# How to place a light inside a clear object

Tags: light

[image: Fire Example]

I've seen it best in The LEGO Movie Series. I want to emit light from inside an object. e.g. how they do fire. I want the object to maintain a plastic look. A translucent plastic.

[image: Current Plastic Material]

I already have a good translucent plastic material. But placing a light inside results in a material I'm not happy with.

[image: Light when mesh is visible]

[image: Light when mesh is hidden]

How can I get this the plastic to look right with a light inside it, while **still emmitting light**?

[image]

Edit: It also doesn't diffuse throughout the brick correctly.

Comment: hello, it's not clear what you mean by "look right", could you precisely show what you have and what you would like?

Comment: @moonboots I'd say the first image illustrates the goal, and the last image his current result :).

Comment: @Zacharoth Why not simply make the flame with an emission material? :)

Comment: oh ok, yes the best should to give emission

Answer (score 1):

This is the result and the node setup:

[image]

Important: set the shader property to this: (alpha blend)

[image]

THe box needs to have transparency, so that the light can "come" out. This does the first mix shader. The second one mixes then the material of the cube with your plastic look (i just took a diffuse shader to simplify it)

a even simpler way would be this:
[image]

UPDATE for cycles:

works too

of course you have to tweak the diffuse material to your plastic material. I just simplified it.
Instead of a lamp i placed another cube with strong emission as light.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I should have prefaced that I am using cycles- So unfortunately your solution won't work.

Comment: i updated my answer. and yes, you should have said it is cycles.